# How to track a string-variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, prototype, ecmascript-5

**Requirement :**
To be able to track string variables in *javascript* by assigning a *unique ID* to each variable.

Example:

```
var a = 'alkd';
var b = 'iquwq';  
console.log(a.id); # 1234
console.log(b.id); # 5678
```

**What I have tried :** I have tried extending string object by adding a new *method* or *property* to *'String.prototype'*

Output :

```
console.log(a.id); #1234
console.log(b.id); #1234 (returning same id as above)
```

**What i have observed :** Ever instance of a string is *inherited* from *String.prototype*. Changes to *String.Prototype* object are propagated to all *String* instances.

Example :

```
a.id = 8783; # setter
console.log(b.id)# returns 8783
```

**My Questions :**

1. Is it actually possible to get required functionality by extending *String Object*?
2. Is there an alternative way to do this?
3. Are there any plans to add this functionality to future editions of ECMAScript?

Comment: strings are immutable so there is no point in tracking it

Comment: Firstly, why? Secondly, that's the whole point of prototypes.

Comment: why wouldnt you just use a json object? a = {id: 1234, value: val};

Answer (score 1):

maybe I don't understand completely what you are trying to do, but if you want to assign an id to a variable and also have a value for that variable along with getters and setters, you can just use a json object

```
// initialize
var a = {id: 0, value: "zero"};

// get
console.log(a.id);
console.log(a.value);

// set
a.id = 1;
a.value = "one";

// get
console.log(a.id);
console.log(a.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1) Nope. What you have observed is correct. Modifying a prototype affects all objects that utilize that prototype. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

2) Yes. Rather than using primitives, you can use a simple object like so:

```
var a = {
    id: 1234,
    value: "abc"
};
var b = {
    id: 5678,
    value: "def"
};
```

3) Probably not... See 1 :)